# Why do characters show up as unicode character codes when plotting to png in R?

Tags: r, homebrew, linuxbrew

After installing R 3.6.3 on our lab's computing cluster, characters no longer show up correctly when plotting to png. For example, the axis label that should be the number 2 shows up as a small box containing the digits "0032", which is the Unicode code for 2 [(as in this example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGlNB.png).
[Plotting to pdf is fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEqM1.png)

R is installed using homebrew, in `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/R`. I suspect this is an issue with R not being installed with proper support for plotting to png, or something along those lines.

This problem is pretty hard to search for, because I kept finding posts about Unicode characters showing up weird symbols, rather than as their codes. So, suggestions on better terms to search would be welcomed! Based on what I did find, we tried (re)installing cairo and pango using brew, and then reinstalling R, but this didn't help.

I have tried to install the Cairo R package in order to be able to use the `CairoPNG` device, but this fails with the message below - it seems R can't find cairo even though it's installed.

```
checking for pkg-config... /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/pkg-config
checking whether pkg-config knows about cairo... no
configure: CAIRO_LIBS is unset, attempting to guess it.
configure: CAIRO_CFLAGS=
checking if R was compiled with the RConn patch... no
checking cairo.h usability... no
checking cairo.h presence... no
checking for cairo.h... no
configure: error: Cannot find cairo.h! Please install cairo (http://www.cairographics.org/) and/or set CAIRO_CFLAGS/LIBS correspondingly.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Cairo’
```

It may be relevant that I am the admin / I do not have sudo access on this machine, so I'm installing R packages into a personal library.

`capabilities()` and sessionInfo are as follows:

```
> capabilities()
       jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua 
       TRUE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE 
   http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
        NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Scientific Linux release 6.10 (Carbon)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/openblas/0.3.9/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.9.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3 tools_3.6.3
```